# Heroku Postgres Typeorm Migrations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, typeorm

I am trying to perform my migrations on the database provided by Heroku, but the following error appears:

```
Error during migration run:
Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1501:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:936:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:710:12) {
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
}
```

ormconfig.js

```
module.exports = {
  type: `${process.env.DATABASE_TYPE}`,
  host: `${process.env.DATABASE_HOST}`,
  port: `${process.env.DATABASE_PORT}`,
  username: `${process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME}`,
  password: `${process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD}`,
  database: `${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}`,
  entities: [`${process.env.DATABASE_ENTITIES}`],
  migrations: [`${process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATIONS}`],
  cli: { migrationsDir: `${process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_DIR}` },
  extra: {
    ssl: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up env variable `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
module.exports = {
  type: `postgres`,
  url: `${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`,
  entities: [`${process.env.DATABASE_ENTITIES}`],
  migrations: [`${process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATIONS}`],
  cli: { migrationsDir: `${process.env.DATABASE_MIGRATIONS_DIR}` },
  extra: {
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }
  }
};
```

Works fine!

Comment: There is the only way I fixed the problem after hours of researches. Thanks you

Comment: Can you help me out with this scenario? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123778/how-can-i-create-a-typeorm-postgres-connection-with-heroku-using-typegraphql